# Whole and fractional hours Double value convert to 12-hour Clock Format time

Tags: javascript, c#, timespan, time-format

In my MongoDB Database, there is collection called BusSchedule with the following fields

BusSchedule

- -Double StartTime --> contains whole and fractional hours
- -Double EndTime --> contains whole and fractional hours
- -String 12hourFormatStartTime
- -String 12hourFormatEndTime

Here are some typical values that might exist

```
StartTime = 6.5 --> contains whole and fractional hours 
EndTime = 9.5 --> contains whole and fractional hours 
12hourFormatStartTime = "06:30 AM"
12hourFormatEndTime = "09:30 AM"

StartTime = 8.5 --> contains whole and fractional hours 
EndTime = 14.25 --> contains whole and fractional hours 
12hourFormatStartTime = "08:30 AM"
12hourFormatEndTime = "02:15 PM"
```

I was wondering if Microsoft had some kind of existing library that could easily convert the Double Data Type representation of  whole and fractional hours  to the 12-hour Clock Format time.

```
StartTime = 8.5  -------translated to-----> 12hourFormatStartTime = "08:30 AM"
EndTime = 14.25  -------translated to-----> 12hourFormatEndTime = "02:15 PM"

StartTime = 6.5 -------translated to-----> 12hourFormatStartTime = "06:30 AM"
EndTime = 9.5 -------translated to-----> 12hourFormatEndTime = "09:30 AM"
```

I'd prefer if I could use C#. I tried to do:

```
  Double wholeAndFractionalHours = 14.25;
  TimeSpan.FromHours(wholeAndFractionalHours).ToString(@"hh:mm tt"))
```

But it throws an System.FormatException "Input string was not in a correct format."

I don't want to waste time writing code to do the aforementioned translation. Could someone please tell me if Microsoft or some 3rd-party open source library will handle the aforementioned requirement?

Thanks @Edin:

Here is what I ultimately ended up coding:

```
 Double wholeAndFractionalHours = 14.25;
 String timeIn12hourClockFormat = (new DateTime().AddHours(wholeAndFractionalHours)).ToString("h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Which one is it? JavaScript? C#? And what does this have to do with MongoDB? Asking for libraries and tools is off-topic. This is also very easy code to write.

Comment: Sorry, I'd prefer if I could use C#.  I tried to do TimeSpan.FromHours(logEventOfInterest.StartTime).ToString(@"hh:mm tt")), but it throws an System.FormatException "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: Huh? How about basic math? 0.5 of 60 = 30; 14 > 12 therefore "PM" and so on. Every language has a time implementation that you can feed "hours" and "minutes". Most even work out that 14 is 2PM for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create new DateTime:

```
var dateTime = new DateTime().AddHours(6.5);
```

And then use `ToString` or `ToShortTimeString` to format the time:

```
string time = dateTime.ToShortTimeString();
```

Or if you explicitly want 12h format with AM/PM:

```
string ampm = dateTime.ToString("h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I think you need `new DateTime().Date.AddHours(...)` otherwise the output will change depending on the current time

Comment: No you don't. `new DateTime()` creates DateTime "01.01.0001 00:00:00". If you would use `DateTime.Now`, than you would need `DateTime.Now.Date`

Comment: sorry, you're absolutely right. I misread it as `DateTime.Now`.